# Using \Q...\E makes regex invalid Perl

Tags: regex, perl, escaping

below is my script that scans each line of the input file against list of annotations. for every occurance 
I tag the term from the line with the annotation tag. The regex works perfectly without \Q..\E operator, but if I don't include \Q..\E I get a range error. So In the situation below I have to keep substitution valid and at the same time take care of the range. Hope the question is clear.

```
 while (<FILE>) {

     chomp $_;

     foreach $word (@array) {

         @cells   = split /\t/, $word;
         $value   = $cells[0];
         $replace = $cells[1];

         chomp $value;
         chomp $replace;
         $_=~s/\Q\b[\w\-]*$value[\w\-]*\b\E)/<$replace>$&<\\$replace>/ig;
     }
     print $_,"\n"; 
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that your `$value` contains regex meta characters. This is easy enough to solve; either use `$value = quotemeta $value;` before matching and leave out `\Q...\E` completely, or put the `\Q...\E` around `$value` only: `$_ =~ s/\b[\w\-]*\Q$value\E[\w\-]*\b/.../ig;`